# Test for null after hitting submit button using ternary or conditional operator

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-operator, session-storage

**What I am trying to achieve:**

I am trying to pass the value of `fileId` as `N` if `sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles')` is `null`. However, if the value exists, I want to pass the existing value from the session storage.

**Scenario 1:**

User may submit a form without uploading the file. In this case, the value of `sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles')` is going to be null.

**Scenario 2 :**

User uploads a file using the `Attach Files` button. So inside `fileUpload` function, I am storing the value of `fileId` in session storage using the following code:

```
 growlComp.show({severity: 'success', summary: 'File Upload successful', detail: 'File Upload was successful'})
 sessionStorage.setItem('uploadedFiles', JSON.stringify(fileArray))
```

**Problem:**

Inside  `mapPropsToValues: props => {`, as shown in the code below,I have tried to put a check using  `var fileIdValue = sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles') ;` 
but this always prints `null` when a submit button is clicked, regardless of someone uploading the file or not.

How can I test for the `null` inside this line of code for the `fileId` variable and if it is `null`, I want to send `fileId: ['N']`, and if it is not `null`, then I want to send the value from the session storage?

I was thinking of using ternary expression but that doesn't fit with if statement.

```
  return {
            createDate: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.createDate || '',
            startDate: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.startDate || '',
            completeDate: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.completeDate || '',
            edwEmployeeId: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.employeeId || '',
            fileId: [sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles')], 
                  
        }
```

Here is my code (many things are removed for brevity purpose)

```
import React from 'react';
import {Field, Form, useField, withFormik} from 'formik';
import {Button, InputLabel,Menu,MenuItem, Select, TextField, TextareaAutosize} from '@material-ui/core'
import * as Yup from 'yup'
import {AutoCompanys} from './forms/AutoCompanys';
//more imports here


const CompanyRequestFormAbc = (props) => {

    const {values, setFieldValue, touched, errors, isSubmitting, handleReset, handleChange} = props;
  

    const fileUpload = (e) => {
        console.log('fileupload triggered....' + e.files)
        const growlComp = growl.current
        
         let formData = new FormData();
            e.files.forEach((file, i) => formData.append(`files`, file))
        
         axios.post('abc/userFileUpload?//some parameters, formData,{
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
            }
        }).then((response) => {
            var filedata = response.data;
            filedata = filedata.filter(v=>v!='');

            var fileArray = [];
            filedata.forEach(element => {
                if(element.indexOf(",")){
                    var splitString = element.split(",");
                    fileArray.push(splitString[0]);
                }
            });

            growlComp.show({severity: 'success', summary: 'File Upload successful', detail: 'File Upload was successful'})
            sessionStorage.setItem('uploadedFiles', JSON.stringify(fileArray))
           
        }).catch((response) => {
            growlComp.show({severity: 'error', summary: 'File Upload unsuccessful', detail: 'File Upload was unsuccessful'})
            console.log('Could not upload files.....')
        })

        


       
    }

    return (
        <div>
           <div id="formDiv">

                <Form className="form-column-3">

                    <div className="form-field">
                        <FileUpload
                            name="files"
                            mode='advanced'
                            uploadHandler={fileUpload}
                            customUpload={true}
                            chooseLabel="Attach Files"
                            multiple={false}/>
                    </div> 
                    
                                        
                    </div> 
                    <div className="btn-group-right">
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary"
                                type="submit">Submit</Button>
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={handleReset}
                                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Reset</Button>
                        <Button size="large" variant="contained" color="primary" onClick={props.onCancel}
                                style={{marginLeft: '5px'}} type="button">Cancel</Button>
                    </div>
                </Form>
            </div>
        </div>
    )

};

export const CompanyRequestEnhancedFormAbc = withFormik({
    mapPropsToValues: props => {
    
       //Test the value of fileId. If the value is null, then we need to send 'N' as an asnwer 
        var fileIdValue = sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles') ;  
        console.log("****************************************************************")
        console.log("fileId value from session storage")
        console.log(fileIdValue);
        if(fileIdValue === null){
            console.log("fileId Value is NULL after null check inside const CompanyRequestEnhancedFormAbc");
        }else {
            console.log ("fileId value is not null inside const CompanyRequestEnhancedFormAbc")
        }
    
    
        return {
            createDate: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.createDate || '',
            startDate: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.startDate || '',
            completeDate: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.completeDate || '',
            edwEmployeeId: props.testRequest && props.testRequest.employeeId || '',
            fileId: [sessionStorage.getItem('uploadedFiles')], 
                  
        }
    },
    validationSchema:validationSchema,
    handleSubmit(values, {props, resetForm, setErrors, setSubmitting}) {
              // Do something
    },
    setFieldValue(field, value, shouldVal) {
        console.log('In setFieldValue')
    },

    displayName: 'Company Request Form',
})(CompanyRequestFormAbc)
```